# Is it possible to scroll left and right in Netbeans with a standard mouse?

Tags: ide, netbeans, scroll

I was wondering if there was a key combination or some setting to change to allow me to scroll left and right easily in NetBeans.

Comment: The enter key can work, if used often enough. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that works on netbeans. In many applications, if you click the wheel button, and move your mouse left and right, you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can hold the `Shift` key and then scroll with the scroll wheel.